# How do I convert a Wikipedia commons image url to the image url (in Java)

Tags: wikipedia

i.e
How do I convert

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KateBushComicRelief.png

to

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/KateBushComicRelief.png

i.e given any wikipedia commons image how do I convert to a valid image url, what is the meaning of *5/5c* ?

Is there  a wikipedia url you can call to convert it ?

Probably not relevant but I am using Java

Comment: See `"url"` field given by `https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&redirects&format=json&titles=File:KateBushComicRelief.png` (got the link from [this discussion](https://community.metabrainz.org/t/how-to-get-the-link-to-a-wikimedia-commons-image/172934)).

Comment: Thankyou okay I will do that although would be nice if could just give url rather than providing json that then requires further parsing.